# Python datetime conversion

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timezone

```
import datetime as dt
from dateutil.tz import gettz
import time

timezone_a = "Japan"
timezone_b = "Europe/London"
unix_time = 1619238722

result = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_time, gettz(timezone_a)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
print(result, timezone_a)
result = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_time, gettz(timezone_b)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
print(result, timezone_b)

# This code prints
""" 
2021-04-24-13-32-02 Japan
2021-04-24-05-32-02 Europe/London

I am trying to reverse it backwards so that input is
2021-04-24-13-32-02 Japan
2021-04-24-05-32-02 Europe/London


And output is 1619238722

"""
```

Hello, I am trying to figure out how to convert a string with a timezone into Unix time. Any help would be apreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

afaik, there is no built-in method in the standard lib to parse IANA time zone names. But you can do it yourself like

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo # Python 3.9+

t = ["2021-04-24-13-32-02 Japan", "2021-04-24-05-32-02 Europe/London"]

# split strings into tuples of date/time + time zone
t = [elem.rsplit(' ', 1) for elem in t]

# parse first element of the resulting tuples to datetime
# add time zone (second element from tuple)
# and take unix time
unix_t = [datetime.strptime(elem[0], "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
          .replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo(elem[1]))
          .timestamp()
          for elem in t]

# unix_t
# [1619238722.0, 1619238722.0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Solution that you provided has COMPLETELY SOLVED my problem that I was stuck on for the last 2 days of my life!

Thanks!

Comment: @PavelBogdanov great to hear, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

See if this code works.

```
# convert string to datetimeformat
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S %Z")

# convert datetime to timestamp
unixtime = datetime.datetime.timestamp(date)
```

Comment: unfortunately, `%Z` strptime directive won't parse IANA time zone names (just unambiguous stuff like "GMT" or "UTC").

Comment: I thank you for answering.
Solution you provided is good for timezones that do not have daylight savings.
I can not use %Z for Chicago because Chicago is GMT-0600 on Tue Mar 09 2021, and Chicago is GMT-0500 on Tue Mar 16 2021.
I would have to convert srting 'America/Chicago' to GMT and I would have to figure out how to calculate GMT first.
Also there might be a way to toss 'America/Chicago' into %Z but I do not know how, or that is not a built in method.
But thank you anyways, that code you provided is useful for some other situations. Thanks!